# LINQ Join on Multiple smallint Columns

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

i am tying to join multiple columns. There is no problem if column type int or string etc.. but my columns types are smallint.

query:

```
    var getworks = (from loc in db.T_location
                            join wl in db.T_vehicle_work_list 
                            on new {x=loc.Route_id, y=loc.Cash_center_num} 
                            equals new { x=wl.Route_id, y=wl.Cash_center_num}

                                        where wl.Route_id == getVehicleRouteId.Route_id && wl.Cash_center_num == getVehicleRouteId.Cash_center_num
                                        && wl.Status_code != "C"
                                        && wl.Instance_id > bfd
                                        && wl.Instance_id < afd
                             select new { loc, wl }).ToList();
```

error : "The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'."

thanx for help...

Comment: What are the actual types in the generated classes? As long as the corresponding column types match, it should work.

Comment: its select form  mssql server. MSSQL Colums types are smallint and model.edmx types are Int16

Comment: ahh i found that problem its about nullable property at model.edmx

Answer (score 0):

If anybody have this problem too. Check the model.edmx column  "nullable" properties are same